# date changes based on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a theory question regarding python dataframes.

I currently have **1 flat file** which has a column called plan start date. When i print the **dtype of this column** it is date **datetime64[ns].**

I have a **second flat file** which has the same column called plan start date. however when i print the **dtype of this column** from the second flat file its is **object**.

I checked through the data for the plan start dates for both these 2 flat files and they are the same.

for example

```
Flat file 1:
Plan start date
8/16/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00


Flat file 2:
Plan start date
8/16/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
5/31/2017 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
4/21/2016 0:00
```

Im kind of unclear why does python interpret these 2 fields differently: one a date time the other an object.

Ps: for the second data frame, I checked the plan start date for any possibility of wrong data i.e strings entered but there is none.

Any one can care to share?

Comment: i'm confused, how are you reading these data? are you getting different results for each file, or the same undesired result for both?

Comment: Im using pandas to read this data. 

So file 2 is a refresh of file 1. Meaning File 1 can be from week 1 and file 2 is from week 2. This is a csv dump from the system. Basically when i print the dtype of plan start date file 1 returns an datetime and file 2 returns a object. Im getting 2 different data types for the same column name basically.

Comment: sort the dates and look at the head and tail.  Probably caused by missing values or inconsistent formatting.

Comment: @Adam I'm saying: "show us the *exact* commands you are using to read the files". Also, @Alexander raises a good point. The output of `df2.describe()` might be informative.

Comment: Ah i realised why. cascading down in the column there are mixed date formats. 

i did df2['plan start date'0.dtype()